# Get the list of all the widgets present in the device

Tags: java, android, widget, appwidgetprovider

I am trying to get the list of provider info for all the widgets, presented in the device from my application. The code snippet is given below:

```
AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
List<AppWidgetProviderInfo> infoList = manager.getInstalledProviders();
```

I have 26 widgets present in my device and it gives list with only 15 widgets' provider info. But as the definition of `getInstalledProviders()` says, it returns a list of the `AppWidget` providers that are currently installed. In case if it gives provider info for only installed appwidgets, then how can i get the complete list of `AppWidget` provider in the device?

Comment: How to get the list of all AppWidgetProvider present in the device not only the installed ones?

Comment: AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        List<AppWidgetProviderInfo> infoList = manager.getInstalledProviders();
        for (AppWidgetProviderInfo info : infoList)
        {
            String providerInfo = "" + info.provider;
            int startIndex = providerInfo.indexOf('{');
            int endIndex = providerInfo.indexOf('}');
            String[] parts = (providerInfo.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex)).split("/");
            String packageName = parts[0]; 
            String widgetProviderName = parts[1];

Comment: the code snippet which iam using to get the list of Appwidget provider info,.